# return to original cell next row with specified beginning cheracter of scanned value

Tags: excel, vba

I am scanning multiple "numerical only"  barcodes across same row until "Z-xxx" is scanned, then auto return to original column +1 row. I want to include the 3 characters that are on the same scan but only after "Z-" in the new cell on the new row. Example: if I scan "Z-123" I want to return to original column and +1 row with cell value = "123".

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    With Target
        If Len(.Value) And .Column > 2 Then
            If .Value = "Z" Then
                Cells(.Row + 1, 3).Select
            Else
                Cells(.Row, .Column + 1).Select
            End If
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this should work

edit: added some error handling to make sure events don't get stuck "off"

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim v

    'skip multi-cell updates
    If Target.CountLarge > 1 Then Exit Sub

    With Target
        v = Trim(.Value)
        If Len(v) > 0 And .Column > 2 Then
            If v Like "Z-#*" Then
                On Error Goto haveError
                Application.EnableEvents = False 
                With Me.Cells(.Row + 1, 3)
                    .Value = Right(v, Len(v) - 2)
                    .Offset(0, 1).Select '? select next cell in new row ?
                End With
                .Value = "" 'clear the original "Z" scan?
                Application.EnableEvents = True
            Else
                Me.Cells(.Row, .Column + 1).Select
            End If
        End If
    End With

    Exit sub

haveError:
    Msgbox Err.Description
    Application.EnableEvents = True

End Sub
```

Comment: Perfect. Thank you

Comment: This code worked perfect last night. Then I saved it and now it wont work. I have tried to save it and I have tried to create a new sheet but still no luck. Any thoughts?

Comment: What do you mean by "won't work"? Does the event fire?  What does it do instead of work?

Comment: The only function that does not work is the "z-" returning the cursor to original column +next row when scanned.  The value scanned is entered in the same row +1 column. Your code worked perfectly last night and accomplished exactly what I intended.But today it did not. Very strange. I will try your fix tomorrow. Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: Have the "Z" values being scanned in changed?  The code checks for the pattern "Z-[digit][other stuff]" so if it doesn't match that pattern it will not go to the next row.

Comment: Yes it has worked. I am not great with vba and I am trying to learn so please forgive me if I don't explain things the best.

Comment: No problem - it's a little difficult for me to offer much help though: I think the code works "as designed" but I might have misunderstood your exact needs.

Comment: Can I ask you to look at 1 more issue I am trying to resolve? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54317166/merge-into-2-columns-the-value-in-column-a-if-duplicate-are-found-in-columns-b1